# HTML Accoridion Panel open by default?

Tags: javascript, html, css, menu, accordion

I came across this animated accordion menu from the W3 Schools site and I really like it, however it does not seem to have any specifics on how to keep a specific section open and "active" by default.

https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_accordion_animate

I tried changing the class of the button to "active" but that did some seem to work, and it only changed the "+" to a "-" sign without showing the menu.

Can anyone advise?

```
<div id="accordion_menu">
                    <button class="accordion">What You Will Learn</button>
                        <div class="panel scrolled">
                            <ul>
                                <li>Fundamental algorithms for signal processing.</li>
                                <li>Techniques for beam forming.</li>
                                <li>Trade-offs among active waveform designs.</li>
                                <li>Ocean medium effects.</li>
                                <li>Shallow water effects and issues</li>
                                <li>Optimal and adaptive processing</li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>  

                    <button class="accordion">Course Outline</button>
                        <div class="panel">
                            <ol>
                                <li>
                                    <p><em>Introduction to Sonar Signal Processing.</em> Introduction to sonar detection systems and types of signal processing performed in sonar. Correlation processing, Fournier analysis, windowing, and ambiguity functions. Evaluation of probability of detection and false alarm rate for FFT and broadband signal processors. </p>    
                                </li>

                                <li>
                                    <p><em>Beamforming and Array Processing.</em> Beam patterns for sonar arrays, shading techniques for sidelobe control, beamformer implementation. Calculation of DI and array gain in directional noise fields. </p>
                                </li>

                                <li>
                                    <p><em>Passive Sonar Signal Processing.</em> Review of signal characteristics, ambient noise, and platform noise. Passive system configurations and implementations. Spectral analysis and integration. </p>
                                </li>

                                <li>
                                    <p><em>Active Sonar Signal Processing.</em> Waveform selection and ambiguity functions. Projector configurations. Reverberation and multipath effects. Receiver design. </p>
                                </li>

                                <li>
                                    <p><em>Passive and Active Designs and Implementations.</em>Advanced techniques for beamforming, detection, estimation, and classification will be explored. Optimal array processing. Data adaptive methods, super resolution spectral techniques, time-frequency representations and active/passive automated classification are among the advanced techniques that will be covered.</p>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <p><em>Advanced Signal Processing Techniques.</em>Advanced techniques for beamforming, detection, estimation, and classification will be explored. Optimal array processing. Data adaptive methods, super resolution spectral techniques, time-frequency representations and active/passive automated classification are among the advanced techniques that will be covered. </p>
                                </li>



                            </ol>

                        </div>  


                    <button class="accordion">Tuition</button>
                        <div class="panel">
                            <p>Tuition for this three-day course is $1890 per person at one of our scheduled public courses. Onsite pricing is available. Please call us at 410-956-8805 or send an email to ati@aticourses.com.</p>

                            <p><a href="https://www.aticourses.com/beta_mobile/register_secure.html">Register Now Without Obligation.</a></p>
                        </div>
                </div>
```

Comment: Post the code that isn't working currently.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please have a look at [tour]. You may also want to check [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [ask], and how to create a [mcve]. Post the code you have tried and the errors you have received. Be as specific as possible as it will lead to better answers.

Comment: Maybe you would like to have a look to Bootstrap accordion: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse-example-accordion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To have the accordion open a specific accordion panel by default (on page load), you can change the script tag from:

```
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
  acc[i].onclick = function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (panel.style.maxHeight){
      panel.style.maxHeight = null;
    } else {
      panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + "px";
    } 
  }
}
```

To this:

```
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
  acc[i].onclick = function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (panel.style.maxHeight){
      panel.style.maxHeight = null;
    } else {
      panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + "px";
    } 
  }
}

// New code to open the first section by default
if(acc.length > 0) {
  acc[0].classList.add("active");
  acc[0].nextElementSibling.style.maxHeight  = acc[0].nextElementSibling.scrollHeight + "px";
}
```

If you don't want to open the first section by default, you can change the 0 to the index of your choice.

[Here is a codepen showing it working](https://codepen.io/peteTalksWeb/pen/aWByJw).

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: @kmark fyi, this is repeating code, it really isn't an ideal way to open a section by default. triggering a click is what I would do, but if you want to go this approach, you should put the code in the `onclick` handler in a function, then call that function in the `onclick` handler and just call the function later in the code.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
  acc[i].classList.toggle("active");
  var panel = acc[i].nextElementSibling;
  panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + "px";
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can manually trigger a click event

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    button.accordion {
        background-color: #eee;
        color: #444;
        cursor: pointer;
        padding: 18px;
        width: 100%;
        border: none;
        text-align: left;
        outline: none;
        font-size: 15px;
        transition: 0.4s;
    }
    
    button.accordion.active, button.accordion:hover {
        background-color: #ddd;
    }
    
    div.panel {
        padding: 0 18px;
        background-color: white;
        max-height: 0;
        overflow: hidden;
        transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <h2>Animated Accordion</h2>
  <p>Click on the buttons to open the collapsible content.</p>

  <button class="accordion">Section 1</button>
  <div class="panel">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
  </div>

  <button class="accordion">Section 2</button>
  <div class="panel">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
  </div>

  <button class="accordion">Section 3</button>
  <div class="panel">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
  </div>

  <script>
    var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
    var i;
    
    for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
      acc[i].onclick = function() {
        this.classList.toggle("active");
        var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
        if (panel.style.maxHeight){
          panel.style.maxHeight = null;
        } else {
          panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + "px";
        } 
      }
    }
      
    /* open second panel by default */
    acc[1].click();
    
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just add in

```
acc[1].click();
```

to the end of the script. You can change out the index to open the section you want to have opened by default.

```
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
  acc[i].onclick = function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var panel = this.nextElementSibling;

    if (panel.style.maxHeight){
      panel.style.maxHeight = null;
    } else {
      panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + "px";
    } 
  }
}

acc[1].click();
```

Comment: @MichaelCoker it sure is, I should have refreshed the page when I came back to answer it.